# Is Rey's Staff Made of Lightsabers?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, lightsaber

Looking at Rey's staff, it sure looks like it is made of lightsabers as parts. [image: Rey's staff]

Are they actually lightsabers? Did she get them (or the whole weapon) from scavenging?

Comment: It DOES look lightsaber-y, but I think we can chalk it up to the designers working within a consistent look for props. Or maybe all shopping at the same plumbing supply store.

Comment: Did they seriously just use half of Maul's lightsaber to make Windu's?

Comment: @Axelrod - well, it WAS sliced in half, so they just needed to spend $1 to spraypaint it. That should explain to you why George Lucas is worth $4Bil

Comment: @DVK It was already that color in the movie, hah. Even cheaper!

Comment: $3,999,999,999(.99) ONLY!

Comment: Of note, model-makers on Star Wars movies have historically been VERY known to re-use items and props throughout the movies. Like [IG-88's head](http://makingstarwars.net/2013/12/a-very-brief-history-of-ig-88s-head/). Even starwars.com has [an article about reused props and costumes](http://www.starwars.com/news/5-recycled-star-wars-props-and-costumes).

Comment: Bear in mind that A) Rey will need parts to construct a lightsaber someday (maybe we'll see the first main-saga lightsaber pike?) and B) Mace Windu's lightsaber as depicted only appears in Episode I. He has a different lightsaber in Episodes II and III, made with electrum to reflect his status on the Jedi Council. Plo Koon, however, has a lightsaber of identical construction to Mace Windu's Episode I lightsaber, except with blue in place of purple.

Comment: i wish we a rey lightsaber pike. closest we ever got to it in any form was this bladebuilders toy: https://www.amazon.com/Star-Wars-Forces-Destiny-Extendable/dp/B01MUGDJYD

Answer (score 26, accepted):

- The Visual Dictionary says "no", or rather doesn't say "yes".

  She did scavenge the quarterstaff but it seems to be a regular normal one, NOT lightsabers - at least I'm pretty sure that if it was, it would have been stated in the Dictionary or the film or the novelization.

  [image: rey's staff]
- Also, to address the fact that it looks too elaborate to be a simple staff - it wasn't "simple" stick:

  > A **multifunction staff** strapped to her back made precision work in such tight and dangerous quarters difficult. *(novelization)*
- Another point indicating it wasn't anything outlandish: staffs apparently weren't uncommon on Jakku, Plutt's flunkies had them too:

  > Coming up beside her, one of Unkar Plutt’s assistants barked at her and gestured in her direction with **his staff**, implying it would be in her best interests to focus on her work and not allow herself to be distracted.
- Rey is very mechanically talented *(source: Visual Dictionary)*. If her quarterstaff was made of lightsabers, I suspect she'd have figured it out by hacking around with it.

---

- ***DISCLAIMER: there's of course an outside chance that it has hidden lightsabers that nobody including Rey knows about and is being held as a surprise for Episode 8. But if so, of course we would have absolutely zero canon information proving or disproving it till then***

  *I could argue that nobody would just leave around a Lightsaber Quarterstaff on a planet that Rey just happened to end up on... but then they left the Map, then BB-8, then Force-using Finn, on that planet too, so I'm not surprised if we find out someone also left a cloning facility, a frozen Dark Jedi, Vader's secret notebook and an abandoned Journal of the Whills there while at it*.
- Some evidence FOR it:

  According to this [forum](https://thecantina.starwarsnewsnet.com/index.php?threads/reys-staff-just-a-staff-more-than-just-a-staff.5602/page-14):

  > Apparently on the Google Star Wars page, the image file of Rey's staff is labeled as "*lightsaber.png*" in the filename. Considering this was probably put together by official marketing people from Disney (or at least the art assets would have come from them) you have to wonder.... Or it could be someone using a popular search term in the filename to help with SEO.

Comment: Of interesting note: her staff looks nearly identical to Darth Plagueis' lightsaber pike.  They may yet decide to change their minds about it.

Comment: @Axelrod didn't Plagueis have a single bladed red lightsaber, just a standard one? where did you get the pike from?

Comment: @Hatandboots [His](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/81hs5ZzZdiL._SY355_.jpg) [official](http://www.starwarspost.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/Plagueis3.1.jpg) [figurines](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Xhcy-QhSDtA/maxresdefault.jpg). He had a staff and a lightsaber that combined into a pike.

Comment: @Axelrod - was that pre-Disney?

Comment: @Axelrod That's odd, every other source I've read has given him a single bladed lightsaber with a slightly longer hilt to allow for two hands, but not a pike.

Comment: Technically, the Visual Dictionary does not say it was not made of old lightsabers, simply that it was salvaged.

Comment: What do you mean by "she loses the quarterstaff"? She certainly has one when she climbs the hill at the end of the movie.

Comment: @TerenceEden oh, I didn't notice that. I'll delete that point then, thanks.

Comment: @DVK Year Released: 2013

Comment: Am I reading this incorrectly, or does the answer say "Force-Using Finn" in it?  Do we have confirmation he's a Force-wielder?

Comment: @Nate - Good point! I am not 100% certain. Can you ask as a question on the main site so I have incentive to dig? :)

Comment: @DVK - Posted, per your request.

Comment: The bits don't appear to be especially lightsaber-y. The bottom bit is a power core and the top bit is merely part of the cover. I can imagine that these are common to a wide range of non-lightsaber electrical items.

Comment: Multifunction quarter-staff... so a [Rod of Lordly Might](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rods/rod-of-lordly-might)?

Comment: It's salvaged (AKA probably pieced together) and Rey didn't believe in fairy tales.  Had you never seen anything from Star Wars, would you know a lightsaber hilt by sight?

Comment: The Rise of Skywalker visual dictionary says that the quarter staff is from a ‘salvaged power conduit’ - though I don’t have an image

Answer (score 2):

In *The Rise of Skywalker*,

> Rey builds a new lightsaber out of the pieces of her staff. While it doesn't seem that her staff was made out of lightsabers to begin with, it at least had similar enough components that it could be used to make one.