# Have we seen this object that Rey has at the end of TRoS before?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

At the end of The Rise of Skywalker, Rey

> holds a fairly gnarly lightsaber. It doesn't look new.

Have we seen it before?

Comment: Don't think so, I think the implication is that she built it but we have no extra material to work off of yet.

Comment: @Valorum This question predates the other one by a week.

Comment: @z0r - We don't base closes on which comes first but which one is more useful. The other has a more descriptive title.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It looks quite similar to the staff she had from the beginning. So probably she has constructed a lightsaber from the handle of it.

Look at this picture of the staff's tip:

[image]

And compare with this image of her new lightsaber:
[image]

Also see [this interesting Stack Exchange discussion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111766/is-reys-staff-made-of-lightsabers).

Comment: They do look somewhat similar but could you expand on this a bit more. Even just some images for comparison (which should be available) would help this answer a lot.

Comment: Whoa that's actually really cool

Comment: The leather wrap on the handle of her new lightsaber is also the same as the wrap on her staff.

Comment: Additionally, the RoS visual dictionary says that her quarterstaff is made from a ‘salvaged insulated power conduit’- so it makes sense she used the staff as the base of her new sabre.

Comment: If Abrams, et. al. are really going for symbolism and pulling from extended sources, I'd also bet that the crystal was Kylo Ren's / now Ben's. There's one story of an unstable red crystal being turned yellow by a Jedi. (  https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jaden_Korr%27s_third_lightsaber ) Wouldn't surprise me if there will be canon (novel, etc.) that describes part of the rise of Skywalker as Rey purifying Ren's crystal.